# Set colours for both dimensions of a stacked bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, geom-bar

I want to produce a stacked bar showing weekly progress towards a goal, where the stacks are different colours and each item in the stack is a different shade of the stack's colour.

Prep:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)
    
teams <- data.frame(
    team = factor(LETTERS[1:6], levels = rev(LETTERS[1:6]), ordered = T),
    goal = c(200, 160, 200, 250, 220, 180))

weeks <- teams %>%
    slice(rep(1:n(), each = 3)) %>%
    mutate(week = factor(rep(c(1:3), 6), levels = c(3:1), ordered = T),
           alph =  1 - 0.1 * as.numeric(week),
           value = c(40, 55, 54, 34, 36, 34, 31, 46, 46, 59, 63, 67, 31, 54, 52, 38, 46, 44),
           week_progress = value / goal) 

teams <- teams %>% 
    inner_join(weeks %>% group_by(team) %>% summarise(progress = sum(value)), by = 'team') %>% 
    mutate(team_progress = progress / goal)
```

I can plot the overall progress and the default colours work well:

```
ggplot(teams, aes(x = team_progress, y = team, fill = team)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', color = 'black', show.legend = FALSE) +
    geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 0.1)(team_progress), 
              x = team_progress + 0.01), hjust = 0)
```

[image: Team overall progress]

I can get close to what I want for the weekly plot using alpha values:

```
ggplot(weeks, aes(x = week_progress, y = team, fill = team)) +
    geom_bar(aes(alpha = alph), stat = 'identity', position = position_stack(), color = 'black', show.legend = F) +
    geom_text(aes(group = week, label = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 0.1)(week_progress), x = week_progress), 
              position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), color = 'blue')

pal <- c(brewer.pal(9, 'YlOrRd')[4:6],
         brewer.pal(9, 'YlGnBu')[4:6],
         brewer.pal(9, 'RdPu')[4:6],
         brewer.pal(9, 'PuBuGn')[4:6],
         brewer.pal(9, 'Greens')[4:6],
         brewer.pal(9, 'BrBG')[4:2]
)
```

[image: Weekly progress]

My questions are:

1. I'm setting the alpha values to 07, 0.8, 0.9, but the values being plotted look to be closer to 0.1, 0.4, 1.0. How do I fix this?
2. If I had a palette of 18 colours (3 weeks x 6 teams, above), how would I apply this to the stacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved like so:

1. The issue with the `alpha` is that you mapped alph on `alpha`. However, the values for `alpha` are chosen by ggplot. To set specific alpha values you can e.g. map `week` on `alpha` and use `scale_alpha_manual` to set the alpha values.
2. To add your colors add the colors as a column to your data, map this column on `fill` and make use of `scale_fill_identity`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

teams <- data.frame(
  team = factor(LETTERS[1:6], levels = rev(LETTERS[1:6]), ordered = T),
  goal = c(200, 160, 200, 250, 220, 180))

weeks <- teams %>%
  slice(rep(1:n(), each = 3)) %>%
  mutate(week = factor(rep(c(1:3), 6), levels = c(3:1), ordered = T),
         alph =  1 - 0.1 * as.numeric(week),
         value = c(40, 55, 54, 34, 36, 34, 31, 46, 46, 59, 63, 67, 31, 54, 52, 38, 46, 44),
         week_progress = value / goal) 

teams <- teams %>% 
  inner_join(weeks %>% group_by(team) %>% summarise(progress = sum(value)), by = 'team') %>% 
  mutate(team_progress = progress / goal)
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)

ggplot(weeks, aes(x = week_progress, y = team, fill = team)) +
  geom_bar(aes(alpha = week), stat = 'identity', position = position_stack(), color = 'black', show.legend = F) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(`1` = 0.7, `2` = 0.8, `3` = 0.9)) +
  geom_text(aes(group = week, label = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 0.1)(week_progress), x = week_progress), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), color = 'blue')
```

[image]

```r
library(RColorBrewer)

pal <- c(brewer.pal(9, 'YlOrRd')[4:6], brewer.pal(9, 'YlGnBu')[4:6], brewer.pal(9, 'RdPu')[4:6], brewer.pal(9, 'PuBuGn')[4:6], brewer.pal(9, 'Greens')[4:6], brewer.pal(9, 'BrBG')[4:2] )

weeks <- mutate(weeks, cols = pal)

ggplot(weeks, aes(x = week_progress, y = team, fill = cols)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_stack(), color = 'black', show.legend = F) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  geom_text(aes(group = week, label = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 0.1)(week_progress), x = week_progress), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), color = 'blue')
```

[image]